# Selective XML Index on SQL Azure Partitioned Table

Tags: xml, azure-sql-database

With the v12 update of Azure SQL, we are now able to create [Selective XML Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670108.aspx) using `CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX` statement.

What I am unable to figure out is how to create this index on a partitioned table so it's aligned with the partition key. For example, including the partition key in the create statement doesn't work: 
`CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX ( PartitionKey, XmlColumn )`. Also specifying `ON ( PartitionScheme( PartitionKey ) )` doesn't work as well.

It seems that selective xml indexes are special beasts. I would very much like to be able to create filtered selective xml index, but again it seems not supported, or I just can't figure out the syntax.

So back to my question: How can we align a selective xml index with a partitioned table or is it always aligned behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selective XML Index (SXI) is basically an internal table that is partitioned in the same manner as the base table. So you don't need to explicitly partition the index unlike other indexes.

Below is a sample script that shows the behavior:

```
use tempdb;
go
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION myDateRangePF1 (date)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('20030201', '20030301', '20030401',
               '20030501', '20030601', '20030701', '20030801', 
               '20030901', '20031001', '20031101', '20031201');

GO
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME myRangePS3
AS PARTITION myDateRangePF1
ALL TO ( [PRIMARY] );
go
create table sxi_t (id int not null, dt date not null, primary key(dt, id), xmlcol xml)
on myRangePS3(dt);
go
CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX sxi_index
ON sxi_t(xmlcol)
FOR(
    pathab   = '/a/b' as XQUERY 'node()',
    pathabc  = '/a/b/c' as XQUERY 'xs:double', 
    pathdtext = '/a/b/d/text()' as XQUERY 'xs:string' MAXLENGTH(200) SINGLETON,
    pathabe = '/a/b/e' as SQL NVARCHAR(100)
);
go

select *
  from sys.partitions as p
  join sys.internal_tables as it
    on it.object_id = p.object_id
 where it.parent_id = object_id('sxi_t');
go

drop table sxi_t;
drop partition scheme myRangePS3;
drop partition function myDateRangePF1;
go
```

As for filtered SXI, if you create a secondary SXI then it is created as a filtered SXI internally on the non-NULL values.

I have filed a bug to update Books Online with some of these details too.